# How to get toState param with $transitions service? (new ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using **ui-router** [1.0.0-alpha.3](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3).
Old events [are deprecated there](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng1_state_events.html#_statechangestart).

so I'm trying to convert

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState) => {
    //...
  });
```

to new way of doing things with **$transitions.onStart** hook -

```
  $transitions.onStart( {}, function($state, $transition$) {
      //...
  });
```

where could I get ***toState*** param in this case?

Comment: I'm having a problem, I try to update a $scope.model but it does not update the DOM ... do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use **$transition$.$to()** for it.

```
$transitions.onStart( {}, function($transition$) {
    // stateTo === $transition$.$to();
    // Check $transition$.$to().name for state name
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow documents, check [Class Transition Methods](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#_to), `toState` in old version equal `$to()` in new version

#### Old version:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, toState, toStateParams, fromState) {
  var oldToState = toState;
}
```

#### New version (current is 1.0.0-beta.3):

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function($transitions){
  var newToState = $transitions.$to();
}
```

From [Interface HookMatchCriteria](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.hookmatchcriteria.html#to):

> This object is used to configure whether or not a Transition Hook is invoked for a particular transition, based on the Transition's "to state" and "from state".

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$transitions.onSuccess({ }, function(trans) {
    stateChangeSuccessCallBack(**trans.$to().self**, trans.params('to'));
});
```

**trans.$to().self** This gives the exact object as in `$stateChangeSuccess(event, **toState**)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition) {
  console.log(transition.params('to').paramname)
})
```

Comment: Although this may be an answer to the question, please add a description to why this will solve this problem. This will help future users when encountering the same problem.